# Two-dimensional aggregation in Histogrammar

Tags: histogrammar

In the examples I found, binning is only performed on a 1D array of data. I would like to bin 2D data in order to simulating the groupby/aggregation of SQL. Is that possible using histogrammar?

(Question reposted from Michel Page.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to aggregate 2D data by nesting 1D aggregators. A simple example is a 2D histogram:

```
hist2d = Bin(numX, lowX, highX, lambda event: event.x,
           Bin(numY, lowY, highY, lambda event: event.y))
```

(Python syntax; substitute lambda-functions for Scala, etc.). The first [`Bin`](http://histogrammar.org/docs/specification/1.0/#bin-regular-binning-for-histograms) aggregator partitions data by `event.x` and passes it on to the second, which happens to be another `Bin` instead of the default [`Count`](http://histogrammar.org/docs/specification/1.0/#count-sum-of-weights).

But you say "simulating groupBy/aggregation of SQL." It's possible to GROUP BY an integer bin number to use an SQL query as a histogram, in which case the Histogrammar example is just a much easier way to do it. However, when people GROUP BY in SQL, they are usually grouping by some categorical data, such as a string.

In Histogrammar, that would be

```
groupedHists = Categorize(lambda event: event.category,
                 Bin(num, low, high, lambda event: event.numerical))
```

Here, [`Categorize`](http://histogrammar.org/docs/specification/1.0/#categorize-string-valued-bins-bar-charts) takes the place of `Bin` to make a new sub-aggregator for each unique string.

Finally, if you're working with an exceedingly large number of categories, you probably want to use the underlying system's (e.g. Spark's) map-reduce functionality to do the aggregation-by-key. If Histogrammar does it, Spark would randomly send data to N workers, each collecting data for all categories, which are then laboriously merged. If Spark does it, Spark will send all data for a given category to the same worker, using less memory overall and making the merging easier.

Here's an efficient version of `groupedHists` in Spark (Scala):

```
val groupedHists =
    rdd.map(event => (event.category, event))
       .aggregateByKey(Bin(num, low, high, {event: Event => event.numerical}))
         (new Increment, new Combine)
       .collect
```

This will give you `(String, Histogram)` pairs, rather than a combined Categorical-Binned histogram as above, but it's the same information.