# Categorical aggregation in Histogrammar

Tags: histogrammar

This is a followup question of SO [Two-dimensional aggregation in Histogrammar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40868077/1623645) (Jim Pivarski created this entry from a private email question):

From:

```
data = [{"item": 'ball', "qty": 3.0}, 
        {"item": 'whistle', "qty": 2.0}, 
        {"item": 'ball', "qty": 5.0}]
```

I want to obtain a sum aggregation using Histogrammar, *i.e.*:

```
ball: 8.0
whistle: 20
```

Following http://histogrammar.org/docs/tutorials/python-numpy/#histogrammar-in-numpy, and Jim's advice in mentioned SO , I try:

```
import histogrammar as hg
data = [{"item": 'ball', "qty": 3.0}, {"item": 'whistle', "qty": 2.0}, {"item": 'ball', "qty": 5.0}]

h = hg.Categorize(quantity=lambda d: d.item, value=hg.Sum(lambda d: d.qty))
for datum in data:
   h.fill(datum)

 print h.toJson()
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a Python issue: since each datum in your example has the form

```
{"item": X, "qty": Y}
```

the way to access it is with `d["item"]` and `d["qty"]`, rather than `d.item` and `d.qty`.

So

```
h = hg.Categorize(quantity=lambda d: d["item"], value=hg.Sum(lambda d: d["qty"]))
for datum in data:
    h.fill(datum)

print h.toJsonString()
```

results in

```
{"data": {"bins:type": "Sum", "bins": {"whistle": {"sum": 2.0, "entries": 1.0},
 "ball": {"sum": 8.0, "entries": 2.0}}, "entries": 3.0}, "version": "1.0",
 "type": "Categorize"}
```

If you change the way your data are represented, you'd have to change the way they're extracted from each `datum`.

Incidentally, Histogrammar-Python has a string-based shortcut that extracts fields as attributes (as you were trying to do) *or* as items (as I did above). The following would work with either kind of data:

```
h = hg.Categorize("item", hg.Sum("qty"))
```

This string-based method will also work if `data` is a dictionary of 1D Numpy arrays (or equivalently, a Numpy Record Array; I don't remember if there's a Pandas hook in there, too). In that case, you'd declare the histogram exactly as above but fill it like this:

```
h.fill.numpy(data)
```

It's the different fill method that interprets the strings differently.

Comment: But SO doesn't seem to be e-mailing me about this tag, even though I set up a filter. I'm going to have to look into that. In the meantime, sorry if my responses are spotty!

Comment: Oh, I just got it. So I should find out by e-mail if you write any other questions with this tag, though with a delay.